# Logging an abstract user in?

Tags: django

I'm currently creating a website with Django and am working on the logging form.

I created a SimpleUser class in my `models.py` file :

```
class SimpleUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.TextField(max_length=40)
    firstname = models.TextField(max_length=40)
    lastname = models.TextField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    GENDER_LIST = (
        (0, 'Homme'),
        (1, 'Femme'),
    )
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=GENDER_LIST, default=0)
    society = models.TextField(max_length=255)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['society', 'username', 'email']
```

Now, here is my logging form in my `views.py` :

```
def loginview(request):
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/moncompte/')
            else:
                errors.append("Disabled account.")
        else:
            if username == "" or password == "":
                errors.append("Fill the two fields!")
            else:
                errors.append("Bad matching account/username.")
    c = {
        'headerlinks': hlinks,
        'footerlinks': footerlinks,   #These are defined earlier
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
        'errors': errors,
    }
    c.update(csrf(request))
    print c
    return jinja_render_to_response('loginview.jhtml', c)
```

Oh and I'm using Jinja too but no problem there :)
The thing is, when I'm trying to log in with this form, Django matches the username and password with the superusers, i.e. the username and password you use to log in the administration pannel. And of course I want to match the log in informations with my objects SimpleUser. And this obviously doesn't work. Any help please ?

Comment: Did you set AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourApp.SimpleUser' in your settings.py ?

Comment: I just changed it, and now when I try to access the admin screen I have this error: AttributeError at /admin/
'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_by_natural_key'

Comment: You must sync your db after setting it. Since the db for your model is already created the best way is to use South to create a migration. Here are the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model

Comment: Thanks. But now I can't log in the admin interface... When I enter the right login informations it tells me "Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."

I tested the admin login informations and some SimpleUser login informations (just to try), but it didn't work :(

Comment: Well actually I can't login anywhere. Admin or login form :(

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, I answered without thinking actually. I hope you can revert the database changes easily. Take a look at the answer below. Think this will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually have to do is create a custom authentication backend and import it in the settings.py file.

```
from models import SimpleUser

class CustomAuth(object):

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = SimpleUser.objects.get(username=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except SimpleUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            user = SimpleUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
            if user.is_active:
                return user
            return None
        except SimpleUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

and in settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('apps.accounts.auth.CustomAuth')
```

Comment: Where do I have to put this CustomAuth class ? Thanks for the response I'm trying it ! :)

Comment: It is not so important. I could suggest you to create a file /accounts/backends.py in your app directory. You should specify the right path when importing in settings.py

Comment: Also, "undefined name 'old_one'". ?

Comment: With old_one I meant if you have any specified backends before to put them there. If not you can simply remove it.